# c++ segmentation error on array returning from method

Tags: c++, arrays

I got the following strange behavior and I cant figure out why it keeps happening consider the following code:

```
class bar{
  private:
    std::string name;
  public:
    bar():name("bar"){};
    std::string getName(){return name;};
};



class foo{
  private:
    bar local_arr[2];
    bar** heapArr;
  public:
    foo(){}; 
    void populate(){
         cout<<&local_arr[0]<<endl; //first
         cout<<local_arr[0].getName()<<endl; //second
         heapArr = new bar*[2];
         for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
           heapArr[i] = new bar();
         }  
    };
    bar* getLocal(){
      return local_arr;
    };

    bar** getHeap(){
      return heapArr;
  }
};

int main()
{
  bar* b = new bar();
  foo & f = *(new foo());
  f.populate();
  bar* local = f.getLocal();
  bar** heap = f.getHeap();
  cout<<&local[0]<<endl;//third
  cout<<local[0].getName()<<endl;//last
  return 0;
}
```

now the output I get is:

1. first - "0x1ea3c70"
2. second - "bar"
3. third "0x1ea3c70" (same address - same object)
4. last - "segmentation fault"

how can it happen it's obvious we are referring to the same object in memory, so why in one place the method works and in other I get this error...

Comment: Was `foo f;` too simple?

Comment: `foo` needs a destructor, copy constructor, and copy assignment operator.  I assume these were elided to reduce the size of the example.  Minimizing the example is the right thing to do, but it's worth commenting for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the following code:

```
heapArr = new bar*[2];
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    heapArr[i] = new bar();
}
```

`heapArr` is created as an array with only **2** elements, but the following `for` loop is trying to access the 3rd element, i.e. it's getting out of the bound of the array and then leads to [UB](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), means anything is possible. For your case, it seems the memory got corrupted.

Change it to

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    heapArr[i] = new bar();
}
```

Comment: Better still, define a constant in one place, and use it twice ... and *even* better, use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<bar>>` and reduce your memory management issues.

Answer (score 2):

Your program has undefined behavior because of the following lines in `populate()`.

```
heapArr = new bar*[2]; // Allocate memory for 2 pointers
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){  // Using heapArray[2] accesses memory using a wrong index.
  heapArr[i] = new bar();
}
```

Make sure that those numbers are same - both 2 or both 3.

```
heapArr = new bar*[2];
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
  heapArr[i] = new bar();
}
```

---

**PS**

I fully encourage use of the language's facility to manage dynamically allocated objects as a learning tool. However, if you are trying to get a working program that solves a real world problem, I discourage use of dynamically allocated memory in application code. You can use containers from the standard library to manage lists, sets, and maps of objects.